# How can I pass data from database that I uploaded on PHP to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I have to make a quiz that will upload from database available choices for answers. I know how to upload from database using PHP. But I made quiz using JavaScript. Is there anyway to to solve this?
I tried something like this in .php file:

```
echo 'new Question("Find correct word.", ["'. $row['right'] .'",
"'. $row['wrong1'] .'", "'. $row['wrong2'] .'", 
"'. $row['wrong3'] .'"], "'. $row['right'] .'"),';
```

And this is where I want to upload words from database in .js file:

```
var questions = [
    new Question("Find correct word.", 
           ["right", "wrong1", "wrong2", "wrong3"], "right"),
];
```

Comment: you can make hidden inputs and assign the values of the data to the inputs. After putting the data to your inputs you can collect them with jquery by using $(#id_element).val()

Comment: And what's the problem with your current solution?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi I don't know how to input jquery.

Comment: @Shadow Don't know. It dosen't work. I have to put uploaded answers from database into .js file.

Comment: <input type='hidden' id='question_1' value='".$row['right']."'>  and jquery-> var question_1 = $('#question_1').val(); alert(question_1 );

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
<script src="js.php"></script>
```

With the following code:

```
var questions=[<?php
echo 'new Question("Find correct word.", ["'. $row['right'] .'", "'. $row['wrong1'] .'", "'. $row['wrong2'] .'", "'. $row['wrong3'] .'"], "'. $row['right'] .'"),';
 ?>];
```

Comment: Do I have to change my .js file to .php or?

Comment: Or you change the php parser so that it also parses js, or you use a router using htaccess and mod rewrite

Comment: I don't know how to do any of that.

Comment: Then rename, its the easiest

Comment: This is where I upload words from data base (this is .php file):
db-to-js.php
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','kviz') or die('Neuspješno spajanje na bazu!');
 $query = "SELECT * FROM rijeci ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Pogreška u spajanju s bazom.');
 $odgovoriArray = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 {
  $odgovoriArray[0] = $row['rijec'];
  $odgovoriArray[1] = $row['kriva1'];
  $odgovoriArray[2] = $row['kriva2'];
  $odgovoriArray[3] = $row['kriva3'];
  print_r($odgovoriArray);
 }
?>

Comment: After I put those word in array like in upper comment, I want to use that array in other external .js file called app.js. There are lot of function, and I want to put those word in this var that is in that app.js file:

var pitanja = 
[
    new Pitanje("Koja je riječ pravilno napisana?", 
 ["Odgovor1", "Odgovor2", "Odgovor3", "Odgovor4"], "Odgovor4"),
];

Is that possible, and if it is, how?

Comment: Shure. May have a look at the basics on.loading js and php

Answer (score 0):

You can echo any php variable in javascript code!

for example :

```
// in php : 

$val = 23 ;



// in js :

var val = <?php echo $val ?>
```

With this way , you can use any php variable in Javascript code, it's because php in compiled in sever before javascript compiles in browser, so php variables are ready to use in JS

Comment: Do I have to change my .js file to .php or?

Comment: Like this?
var pitanja = 
[
  new Pitanje("Koja je riječ pravilno napisana?", ["<?php echo '. $row['rijec'] .'?>", "<?php echo '. $row['rijec'] .'?>", "<?php echo '. $row['rijec'] .'?>", "<?php echo '. $row['rijec'] .'?>"], "<?php echo '. $row['rijec'] .'?>") ?>
];

Comment: Hi ! , sorry @RobiZzT for being too late!  I think the Js code should be directly in you php file in `<script>`  tag!